# Correcting for correlation of kernel density of events to that of their distance from separate feature using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, kernel-density, autocorrelation, normalize

I have a kernel density raster of recorded events. These events are correlated to their distance from a linear feature. In other words, density is higher near this line because it is a 'starting point' and the events dissipate as they get further away. I want to account for this so as to measure a density independent of distance, so I can effectively compare the raster to other features in the landscape.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.

Comment: If you also want to ask about QGIS that can be done in a separate question where you describe what you have tried and where you are stuck using that software.

Comment: If the effect of distance is equal all along the line, normalisation does nothing, doesn’t it?

Comment: Do you have the event location data as well as the kernel density? It sounds like you want to fit an inhomogeneous point pattern with distance-to-linear-feature as a covariate.